# Showing that $a, b$ are relatively prime given that $a|c$ and $b|c \implies ab|c$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we have $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that the following holds:

For any $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a|c \land b|c \implies ab|c$. Show that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Now, I have listed what I know:

- $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = am$
- $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = bn$
- $\exists r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = rab$

Suppose we have $d$ = gcd($a,b$), then $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$ax + by = d$.

I then tried to multiply both sides by $c$ and hoped that $d$ will be 1 somehow, but it's probably not what is sought after.

This is practice for an examination question by the way.

Comment: So $4$ and $6$ cannot satisfy your condition (since $4$ and $6$ are not relatively prime). What is the smallest positive integer divisible by $4$ and divisible by $6$ but *not* divisible by $4 \cdot 6 = 24$? (Does this give you any further insight into the problem?)

Comment: 12? Correct me if I am wrong, but we already have the implication that $ab|c$ is true. I mean, if we suppose that $a|c \land b|c$

Answer (score 1):

If it works for *any* c, then in particular it works for $c = \operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$.

Comment: Sadly, I have not looked at lcm yet. The concept of the lcm is relatively easy I supposed, but I have not dealt with it in all its glory yet. Is there an alternative way to think about it?

Comment: @AstroMase How about $c=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$? We then have $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ (the easiest way to show that is just to stare at the prime decompositions), but if $ab\mid c$, that means $ab\leq c$, which again means $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Try use $gcd(a,b)\ lcm(a,b) = ab$ for any choices of positive integers a and b, because the assumption is that $lcm(a,b)<c$